# FreeIPA - Please explain the enroll vs add host permission

Tags: freeipa

I want to create a user in my FreeIPA domain that will be able to automatically add and delete a host created (or deleted) by Foreman. 
I found 2 permissions:

- "System: Add Host" and
- "System: Enroll a Host".

What is their difference?

Answer (score 0):

According to RHEL7 documentation `host-add` [1] sets a DNS entry in the IPAs DNS server.
Enrolling is linked to the `ipa-client-install` and should be what you need.

Depending on your setup, you might need both, since `host-add` can be involved during the enrolling of new clients. In case your IPA server does not do DNS, this might not be the case.

[1] https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/linux_domain_identity_authentication_and_policy_guide/adding-host-entry

Comment: The case is simple: 
I want to automatically "register" hosts provisioned by Foreman/Katello. Also, I want to register hosts created in AWS and managed by Chef. 
So, host add probably is not enough.

Comment: `Host Add` is for sure not enough. But I assume you need both, when FreeIPA is your DNS server and you want to have working DNS entries.

Comment: Correct. And you need a bunch of other permissions as well. Thankfully, the latest Katello has a script to do this for me :)